# Run Gitlab CI pipeline for merge request only once

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to create Gitlab CI job that should be run when merge request is created.

I could use example from documentation:

```
some-job:
  script:
    - echo "Test"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

Above job will be executed when merge request is created, which is ok. But it also will be triggered when new commits will be pushed to the existing merge request.

Is it possible to run job exactly once, only when merge request is created?

Comment: i don't believe there is a way to accomplish what you want, nor would i recommend that you do it if you could, since the first pipeline would not match the latest commit if someone updated their branch (pipelines are tied to commits, not branch names or MRs).

are you wanting to just clean up the noise on the pipeline page?

Comment: @ericfossas, I'm integrating Gitlab with bug tracker. I just need to create comment in the relevant ticket saying that merge request was created. I won't be looking at particular commit details at all.

Comment: This does not belong in CI IMHO, you'd rather want to use a hook that push the "created MR" event to your bug tracker.

Comment: The easier thing would be to have the job always run, but use conditional logic within the job itself to determine when to apply changes in your bug tracker. For example, you may check if the comment already exists.